# How to solve system of equation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, algebra

I'm trying to do do some algebra in JavaScript based on some conditions and known variables but I'm not good enough at maths or JavaScript to understand how to write it.

So here's the conditions:

```
var w1 = h1/1.98

var w2 = h2/0.6355

h1 = h2

w1 + w2 = 1367
```

I'm not 100% sure but I think there may be enough info here to find out what w1, w2, h1 and h2 are.

Does anyone know how I can create this calculation?

Comment: Are these equations fixed? Or then can change too?

Comment: If this is just an algebra question, it is nothing to do with javascript.

Comment: I need to write it in javascript. The figures I've put in will actually be variables that will change.

Comment: What has this to do with Javascript? `w1 ~ 332,1`, `w2 ~ 1034,9` and `h1 = h2 ~ 657,6`.

Comment: This is a system of equations. Do you want to implement a solver in javascript?

Comment: @Keyser I'm well aware this is a system of equations. I need to write a javascript algorithm to calculate w1, w2, h1 and h2 using the conditions above. h1 needs to be the same as h2. w1 + w2 must equal 1367.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution with variables as you need:

```
function algebra(c1, c2) {
  /* Given these equations
  w1 = h1/c1
  w2 = h2/c2
  h1 = h2
  w1 + w2 = 1367; */

  var w1 = 1367 * c2 / (c1 + c2), h1 = w1 * c1;
  return {w1:w1, w2:1367-w1, h1:h1, h2:h1};
}
```

Comment: Just making a variation of this to work with my code, will let you know if it works for me. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

If it is an algebra question... since h1 = h2 you may exclude them and get.

```
w1*1.98 = w2*0.6355
w1 + w2 = 1367
```

Put it into [some solver](http://wims.unice.fr/wims/en_tool~linear~linsolver.en.html) and get

{ w1 = 332.1462435480787, w2 = 1034.853756451921 }.

Comment: I see, I'll give this a go in my code and see if I'm getting all the right figures.

Comment: Thanks for this but it's not really just the algebra I'm trying to work out. Here you suggest using some solver to work out the anwer but I need to get the answer with javascript.

Comment: There are also some solvers in JavaScript (such as [Nerdamer](https://nerdamer.com/)) that can solve systems of equations like this one.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if anyone's reading here any more, but here you go:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/matgts/files/jsmath/

Access "index.html". Some of the programs require at least Firefox 3 or 4, because of , but the one which solves systems of equations should run in earlier versions (and up to the latest one, of course). Easy to use, download and run offline, like JavaScript programs are always supposed to run. For accessing web sites, NetSurf is the best (https://www.netsurf-browser.org/), no JavaScript. JavaScript is a great language, just not online, where it's just a great nuisance.

A JavaScript function which uses Cholesky's method (the program mentioned above uses Gauss elimination) is included here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/matgts/files/jswall/

The file is "js/chol.js", the comment above the function says how the elements of the matrix should be organized.

Equivalent C functions are also provided. All GPL version 3.

P.S. I tried to post the message with NetSurf and it didn't work, apparently this site has some serious problems, which I find surprising for a site about programming, I would have expected its creators to know something about the subject.